# SSL certificate for a pointed domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, domain-name, domain-transferring

I have a domain hosted by GoDaddy and I have just bought a vps server (without domain) and an SSL certificate (not used) from 1&1.

Could I use my SSL certificate for that domain if I just point it to 1&1 DNS, or I need to transfer the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to serverfault.  In short, yes you can.  Though there is a little more to it than just pointing to it.

You will need to install a webserver on your VPS.  It will have to support HTTPS (I would recommend not using SSL and only using TLS 1.2).  You will need to provide the certificate in the right form.  You can usually follow the guides for your certificate provider for your webserver of choice.  Generally you provide a request, this is turned into a key, the provider signs it and give you back a certificate.  Sometimes you need to provide an intermediate certificate too.

You have the option of using the DNS feature at GoDaddy.  Or point the DNS servers for your domain to 1&1.  Or transfer the domain to 1&1.  Its up to you.  Personally I don't like to have everything in one place.  Then in DNS you need to point the `A` (or `CNAME`) DNS record to the IP address (or host) of your webserver.  That webserver will then either have to be configured to respond to all HTTPS requests on its IP (or if you wish to terminate multiple HTTPS sub/domains on the same IP you will have to look into SNI).  DNS takes some time to propogate, though usually for new records once the Zone is updated you can query it right away.

When you have the webserver, DNS and HTTPS side all setup I can recommend the [SSL Server Test at Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). It will help identify any configuration problems and give you tips on choosing more secure option in your webserver (edit: from an HTTPS perspective - you should consult other methods for securing your app/vps).

I think you will be back for more questions - please feel free to use search and all the wonderful guides out there.  Many people have been where you will be going and have documented it very well for the webserver you may choose.  Good luck.